# KivyMD Buttons : How increase its dimensions

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to increase the `width` and the `height` of a `kivyMD button`, but it is not supported (size_hint).

•Should I make my own button class that inherits from the Button class ?

•Would that be bad considering I want my app to go on android ?

I would like to know if anyone solved this issue before. Also, if I increase the dimensions of the button, I want the size of the text to change, too...

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post but I ran into the same issue.
I had to use it a percentage of the root width and it worked.
Example below:

```
MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Some text"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
            size_hint: None, None
            width: root.width*0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

For example with MDRaised button type
This is how you do it:

```
MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Do Something"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.do_anything()
        size: 30, 30
        size_hint: None, None
```

Make sure you set *size_hint* to **None, None** and then specify ***size: width, height***

Comment: but it makes no effect for me .... : ( does it work on your machine ? or it's just me lol : ( could you provide a minimum example of code ? ( full code instead of part of the kv stuff ) thx  : )

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem, none of the existing answers works for me. The following works (KivyMD 1.1.1):

```
MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Some text"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
            _min_width: 300
```